# Emacs color theme causes the minibuffer to disappear?

Tags: emacs

Here is a link to my color theme that causes the problem

https://gist.github.com/3d8cc59cbc1c7f87817f

Does anyone have any idea why it is removing the minibuffer?

This problem only occurred after installing and using this with the emacs-starter-kit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the emacs-starter-kit, the lines in your themes which affect the mini-buffer look fine.

Comment: Yeh it works without the starter kit, but I really want to use the starter kit. The kit i am using is: https://github.com/eschulte/emacs-starter-kit. Thanks for looking, any other ideas?

Comment: Personally I'd avoid the starter kit and just install the specific features you want, your Emacs configuration is something you want to be well on top of. BTW, I did a grep for `minibuffer` in the starter-kit and nothing in there looked funky, so I would be doing a step by step test of each feature to see which one failed, at this point.